# test-on-borrow config in hikariCP

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp

I have spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE project and I want configure datasources with pool connection.

I use Spring data JPA + hibernate + HikariCP:

```
#DataBase properties
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=***
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
# Hikari
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
#jpa config
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

In #DataBase properties - I think everything is fine

In #Hikari - I do not know how implement this:

in tomcat I can write `spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true` but how can I make like this with Hikari ?

And mayby I forgote some important configs?